# netbeans 6.7.1 autocomplete question

Tags: php, netbeans, autocomplete

I am using Netbeans 6.7.1 to code in PHP. I have a problem with autocomplete.
If I write strrev  get no autocomplete for it if I press CTRL+space and then I type str I get a list of function names including strrev.

My question is: Is there no way to make this automatic like in Visual Studio or Zend Studio and not have to press CTRL+space for the autocomplete feature to activate itself for function names? I would like to type str and be presented with a list of functions without having to press Ctrl+Space. Does anyone know how I can do that?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try upgrading to Netbeans 6.8, the autocomplete behaviour seems to have changed to popup without requiring <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>space</kbd>.